# What is considered to be "inside of Metro" for "Express train" assignment.

Tags: battlefield-4

Second assault assignment "Express train" has following criteria:

- 1 Assault Rifle Ribbon
- 2 Kill Assist Ribbons in round
- 10 Kills inside the Metro on Operation Métro in round

While playing on Operation Métro map in Conquest mode I get a lot of kills around B, yet only very few of these count towards the assignment. Which part of map is considered to be "inside Metro"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Second Assault assignments are quite glitchy so there might not be a clear answer as to what the game considers "inside the Metro", but it seems to be the lowest level running alongside the trains. You would think that the section up the stairs but still inside the main building would be included but it doesn't seem to be. I was near the elevators on the lower level when I completed the assignment (I killed an enemy who was near the door to the little side path leading upstairs). Also, there seems to be support for this from an EA employee at the [EA answers forum](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/In-the-assignment-Express-train-what-does-it-mean-to-get-10/td-p/2039129).

I'm not sure if both you and your victim need to be on the lower level or if it's just you or just him, but your best bet is to fight on the lower level and go for targets that are also on the lower level.

Good luck.